# What's the title of this song from Sekaiichi Hatsukoi 2?

Tags: music, sekai-ichi-hatsukoi

I've been looking for a certain song since yesterday, and I can't find it. It played at the last episode (12) of the second season of Sekaiichi Hatsukoi; it's at the part where Masamune sat on a bench at a subway station, and he held Ritsu's hand. The song started at 21:39, and it played before Aikotoba (the ending song).

Comment: Okay, I think it's just Aikotoba, but piano version. Why did I realize it just now? Well, if it's otherwise, please tell me the title of the OST. orz

Answer (score 2):

Deleted previous answer. You can always look at the edit history if you want to see it again. :)

[image]

Is this the scene when the piano bit plays for a while? If it is then it is actually part of the ending song.

I am not too sure why they decided to play it at that moment before the ending song but I am fairly certain it's part of the ending song.

---

FYI ;): If you listen really closely, that same tune is actually part of the ending song (Aikotoba) itself at [1:27](http://youtu.be/ZJPEMmIf7A4?t=1m27s) (it's actually part of the ending song).

Comment: It doesnt really sound the same...

Comment: @Gerret - Sorry for the late reply. A bit busy but actually it is. http://youtu.be/fj0_RARPZD8?t=1m36s

Comment: I think you missunderstand the question. He means the OST that starts exactly at 21:39. It is the piano with some synth like violin melodie. The song you searched up is the OST before. This is only a short melodie till 21:56. I think that it is a intro like melodie for the ending song of the anime.

Comment: @Gerret- Just wondering but is the OP talking about the Piano bit before the ending song but which plays directly after the link I have above? I am not familiar on what that is. Maybe it is an improvisation but I am not sure. I will have a look online to check but so far haven't found anything.

Comment: Actually it is the ending song. You can hear that bit at 1:27. http://youtu.be/ZJPEMmIf7A4?t=1m27s

Comment: Yea I said so... you should edit your answer...

Comment: Yep. Edited. I feel very dazed right now for some strange reason.... XD

Comment: Yea now it is right! :3